# Unable to handle kernel paging request at XXXXXXXXX

Tags: c, linux, kernel-module, libusb, udev

I am trying to create a kernel module which needs to find whether a specific USB device is attached or not namely a **USB Keyboard** and whether It has DMA access or not.

To achieve this I am traversing through all the URB structures (linux/usb.h) present in the RAM. When I find a struct that is not null, I am trying to access the device information via struct usb_device *dev pointer declared inside URB structure. 
However access to any information inside the *dev results in an OOPS condition with the bug stating Unable to handle kernel paging request at ffffe00121160800. The address remains constant every time.

The following is just a snippet of my whole kernel module.

```
#define x(y) ((void *)((uint32_t)(y)+PAGE_OFFSET))
static int __init check(void)
{
unsigned long long i;
for(i = 0; i < ULLONG_MAX; i += 0x10)
{     struct urb *urbptr = (struct urb *)x(i);
if((((unsigned long)urbptr->dev) % 0x400) == 0) 
   {
    if ((((unsigned long)urbptr->transfer_dma) % 0x20) == 0)
    {
      if (urbptr->transfer_buffer_length ==8)
      {
        if (urbptr->transfer_buffer_length ==8)
        {
          if (urbptr->transfer_buffer !=NULL)
          {
            if(urbptr->dev !=NULL)
             {
                printk("\n%s\n",urbptr->dev->product);
             }
          }
        }
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

The error occurs each time I try to access any value of a usb_device structure (not just char * product). After a lot of debugging I was able to identify that the error occurs only at the printk statement i.e the *dev is not null, the pagefault occurs only when I am trying to access its data members.

[Source of struct usb_device](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/usb.h#L544)

[Source of struct urb](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/usb.h#L1452)

---

Here is the **dmesg** output:

```
[   93.925232] BUG: unable to handle kernel paging request at ffffe00121160800
[   93.925287] IP: [<ffffffffc01320f0>] check+0xf0/0x1000 [check]
[   93.925334] PGD 0 
[   93.925350] Oops: 0000 [#1] SMP 
[   93.925375] Modules linked in: check(POE+) ctr ccm nvram msr pci_stub vboxpci(OE) vboxnetadp(OE) vboxnetflt(OE) vboxdrv(OE) bnep rfcomm binfmt_misc nls_iso8859_1 uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_core v4l2_common videodev media rtsx_usb_ms memstick btusb bluetooth 6lowpan_iphc fglrx(POE) ip6t_REJECT xt_hl ip6t_rt nf_conntrack_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv6 ipt_REJECT xt_LOG xt_limit xt_tcpudp xt_addrtype nf_conntrack_ipv4 nf_defrag_ipv4 xt_conntrack ip6table_filter ip6_tables nf_conntrack_netbios_ns nf_conntrack_broadcast nf_nat_ftp nf_nat nf_conntrack_ftp nf_conntrack iptable_filter ip_tables x_tables wl(POE) arc4 iwldvm mac80211 dell_wmi sparse_keymap dell_laptop dcdbas snd_hda_codec_hdmi intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic kvm_intel kvm snd_hda_intel snd_hda_controller snd_hda_codec crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul snd_hwdep ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel aes_x86_64 lrw gf128mul snd_pcm glue_helper ablk_helper cryptd snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi snd_seq joydev serio_raw iwlwifi cfg80211 snd_seq_device snd_timer snd lpc_ich soundcore mei_me mei amd_iommu_v2 mac_hid shpchp parport_pc ppdev lp parport rtsx_usb_sdmmc rtsx_usb i915 psmouse ahci libahci i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper drm r8169 mii wmi video
[   93.926369] CPU: 3 PID: 3410 Comm: modprobe Tainted: P           OE 3.16.0-41-generic #57~14.04.1-Ubuntu
[   93.926439] task: ffff88008b7fd180 ti: ffff880221114000 task.ti: ffff880221114000
[   93.926448] RIP: 0010:[<ffffffffc01320f0>]  [<ffffffffc01320f0>] scan_start+0xf0/0x1000 [check]
[   93.926449] RSP: 0018:ffff880221117d28  EFLAGS: 00010282
[   93.926450] RAX: 0000000000000005 RBX: 0000000000207f40 RCX: 0000000000004c00
[   93.926451] RDX: 000000000000e76a RSI: 0000000000000046 RDI: 0000000000000246
[   93.926453] RBP: ffff880221117d40 R08: 0000000000000092 R09: 0000000000061bd7
[   93.926454] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: ffff880221117ac6 R12: ffffe00121160800
[   93.926455] R13: ffff880000000000 R14: ffffffffc0132000 R15: ffffffffc1c42000
[   93.926457] FS:  00007f3eb6c9e740(0000) GS:ffff88025f2c0000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[   93.926459] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[   93.926460] CR2: ffffe00121160800 CR3: 00000002210c3000 CR4: 00000000001407e0
[   93.926461] Stack:
[   93.926464]  ffffffff81c1a020 ffff8802371db940 0000000000000000 ffff880221117db8
[   93.926466]  ffffffff81002144 0000000000000001 0000000000000001 0000000000000002
[   93.926468]  ffff8802502e4140 0000000000000001 ffff880221117da0 ffffffff8119d672
[   93.926469] Call Trace:
[   93.926479]  [<ffffffff81002144>] do_one_initcall+0xd4/0x210
[   93.926488]  [<ffffffff8119d672>] ? __vunmap+0xb2/0x100
[   93.926498]  [<ffffffff810edc91>] load_module+0x13c1/0x1b80
[   93.926505]  [<ffffffff810e9840>] ? store_uevent+0x40/0x40
[   93.926510]  [<ffffffff810ee5c6>] SyS_finit_module+0x86/0xb0
[   93.926519]  [<ffffffff8176de4d>] system_call_fastpath+0x1a/0x1f
[   93.926631] Code: 24 68 00 74 38 31 c0 48 c7 c7 4b 10 c4 c1 e8 b2 c5 62 c1 4d 8b 64 24 48 4d 85 e4 74 20 48 c7 c7 50 10 c4 c1 31 c0 e8 9a c5 62 c1 <41> 8b 34 24 48 c7 c7 56 10 c4 c1 31 c0 e8 88 c5 62 c1 48 c7 c7 
[   93.926636] RIP  [<ffffffffc01320f0>] check+0xf0/0x1000 [check]
[   93.926639]  RSP <ffff880221117d28>
[   93.926641] CR2: ffffe00121160800
[   93.940769] ---[ end trace f2349a61d7dd6264 ]---
```

---

Is there any reason for the kernel not being able to access this particular structure? Even if that kernel space is write protected I am only trying to read it. commands like **lsusb** access the same struct while in userspace so I believe there should be no reason that this kernel is over stepping its bounds.

Comment: I would suspect that in urbptr->dev is some gibberish and therefore it passes your check for NULL. (also does that if even work? you have two instead of one Left parenthesis there). I am no expert in usb drivers by any means, but urb struct has status variable, it would be worth checking what is in there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Edited the code - the parenthesis was a typo, its not there in the actual code :)
Also, the problem isn't in the urb struct - so checking its status variable would be redundant, although the status variable does something completely different and is irrelevant in this situation.
The problem resides in when I am trying to print (or use) whatever is there inside the usb_device struct. And if there is gibberish there (which I might not be expecting), is there any way to check it apart from NULL?

Comment: `for(i = 0; i < ULLONG_MAX; i += 0x10)` That is a nice loop you got there. Would be sad if something nasty happened to it.

Comment: Well,  documentation says it should be null if nothing else. But that's documentation and not everybody can go by it. That's why I thought status could point out some error, but if you say it's not helpful, I really don't know how to check. But I am kinda curious where you've got that loop implementation from. It looks to me just like going trough all the addresses, but there can be anything.

Comment: What makes you think `x(i)` is an urb? You seem to be casting the whole of memory to `urb` and then act surprised that doesn't work...

Comment: @Jester - Sir I am trying to implement the concept of a well extablished paper - http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~mikepo/papers/gpukeylogger.eurosec13.pdf. And if I remove the printk statement assuming that I do not refer to usb_device struct at all, the loops run till the time the loop condition holds. If this is not right which I believe is, as the paper states, then in what way would you believe mem traversal can be done? Although that is not the question I asked.

Comment: @backman - The status variable is used - as the doc states to get the "status of the particular request", Which in this case is irrelevant. The loop is traversing for the all the memory addresses along the lines of 0x400 as that mem space is the kernel space for storing USB structures

Comment: I think @Jester said it nice, you are going trough memory and expecting that everything there is urb. If you remove printk it won't fail because you are not accessing that memory place. Casting doesn't access it, that's why it fails at printk not before. It seems to me you are missing some essentials skills in pointer mechanics of C language. The code in paper you mentioned is pure pseudo-code. Author mentions scanning just pages allocated by kernel.

Comment: @backman Jester might be right. However this implementation and concept has been discussed and published in numerous journals and papers. So implementing it in some or the other is surely possible. I guess I'll have to reconsider the loop condition if anything else. Thanks for your help. :) I'll update the loop and see if it works